# I only get the output "no valid permutation found"

Tags: python

`From this code I get only "no valid permutation found"

```py
from itertools import permutations
from sympy import isprime

def reorder_vector(vector):
    # Extract unique numbers from the vector
    unique_numbers = set(vector)

    # Generate all permutations of the unique numbers
    perms = permutations(unique_numbers)

    # Iterate over the permutations
    for perm in perms:
        # Find the positions of 8s and 9s in the vector
        eights = [i for i, num in enumerate(vector) if num == 8]
        nines = [i for i, num in enumerate(vector) if num == 9]

        # Check if the permutation satisfies the rules
        if (
            all(vector[i] == 8 for i in eights) and
            all(vector[i] == 9 for i in nines) and
            all(vector[i-1] != vector[i+1] for i in nines if i+1 < len(vector)) and
            any(vector[i] == vector[i+2] for i in range(len(vector)-2)) and
            all(vector[i] % vector[i+1] == 0 for i in range(len(vector)-1)) and
            isprime(vector[-1])
        ):
            # Reorder the vector according to the permutation
            reordered_vector = list(vector)
            perm_index = 0
            for i in range(len(vector)):
                if vector[i] == 8:
                    reordered_vector[i] = 8
                elif vector[i] == 9:
                    reordered_vector[i] = perm[perm_index]
                    perm_index += 1
                else:
                    reordered_vector[i] = vector[i]
            return reordered_vector

    # If no valid permutation is found, return None
    return None


vector = [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8, 8, 9, 9]
reordered_vector = reorder_vector(vector)
if reordered_vector:
    print(reordered_vector)
else:
    print("No valid permutation found.")`
```

I was trygin to generate a number with 11 characters with the following rules:
All existing 8s are next to each other

● All 9s are separated from each other by a number which is unique in the
vector

● Two different numbers each appear twice in the vector and are
separated from each other by at least one 8

● All 3s are surrounded by the same number

● Numbers in positions 5, 6, and 7 are divisible by the same number

● The number in the second last place is divisible by the one in the last
place

● The number in the last position is a prime

Comment: I may be wrong, but I see that you both check that ALL `vector[i-1] != vector[i+1]` AND check that ANY `vector[i] == vector[i+2]`... So you seem to both say that all  two apart must be different, and there must exist at least one pair of two apart that are not different.

Comment: so how could it be changed

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. For example, "two numbers each appear twice", but there are 11, so one number must appear only once or three times etc.? And positions 5, 6, 7 are divisible by the same number. This number could be 1, as long as they're integers this holds. Try to update the question for clarity. :)